# How do I filter items listed on a page using a MySQL query without refreshing the page?

Tags: php, mysql, ajax, forms

I have a page which generates an audio playlist from tracks in a MySQL database using a select query, i.e.

```
$query1="SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE uploaded_page='$this_path_short' ORDER BY id DESC";
```

I would like the user to be able to filter the playlist in various ways, and the plan is to have a series of radio buttons in a form that will generate a new MySQL query to list just the required tracks.

I would like to know the best way of updating the playlist with this query.  Ideally this would be done without refreshing the page.

Comment: I really hope you're [properly escaping your SQL query](http://bobby-tables.com/php).

Answer (score 3):

Add AJAX in head:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Example of use with buttons:

```
  <a href="#" onClick="$('#content_s').load('/sql.php?value=some_path');">News</a>
```

You can edit hover of $content_s in your CSS file if you want.

And to display data in your html:

```
<div id="content_s">
 </div>
```

Your sql.php file would be like:

```
<?php
$this_path_short = $_GET['value']; // stay frosty, it's SQLi vurnable, but this will get "some_path" I belive. I didn't test this though, but it should work
$query1="SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE uploaded_page='$this_path_short' ORDER BY id DESC";
...
```

You can generate links with PHP

**EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT EDIT**

index.php
You said that the path to the playlist is in index.php so:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Playlist</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js"></script> 
</head>
<?php $path = 'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Jx0oOZmY5KM'; ?>
<div id="menu">
<a href="#" onClick="$('#content_s').load('playlist.php/?val=<?php echo $path ?>');">Load Playlist</a>
</div>
<div id="content_s">
</div>
</html>
```

playlist.php:

```
<?php
$this_path_short = $_GET['val']; 
echo '$this_path_short = ' .$this_path_short.'<br>';
echo 'This is how the query looks like right now: "SELECT * FROM tracks WHERE uploaded_page=\''.$this_path_short.'\' ORDER BY id DESC";';
?>
```

This example will give you the idea of how it works

1.

[image]

2.

[image]

Comment: Thanks.  I can now see how content can be added to my page, but how would I update the sql query which selects the content?

Comment: just change news.txt to your sql_query.php?value=this_path_short page and after clicking the button, $this_path_short = $_GET['value']; Of course this is just an example, and it is vournable to SQL injection, but you get the idea, right?

Comment: Thanks. Just trying to make sure I have understood you.  It will get the value(s) from the form, and then somehow pass this to the  query I already have on the page?  It's the second part that I am still unclear about

Comment: Ah thanks, that's clearer now.  How do I set the value of `$this_path_short` on page load, i.e. before any filtering using the form?

Comment: Make a loop in PHP that echos those AJAX buttons. How do you generate $this_path_short right now?

Comment: It's constructed from the full path of the index.php page that the playlist is on using php, and set at the top of index.php

Comment: <a href="#" onClick="$('#content_s').load('/sql.php?value=<?php echo $this_path_short; ?>');">Path = <?php echo $this_path_short; ?></a>

Comment: Sorry, now I am confused again. I want to update the query that builds the playlist on the page.  I am not sure where the content_s DIV comes in to my setup.  I am not really wanting to load new content on to the page am I?  I am just wanting to get values from the form, pass these to the query and somehow run this query again without refreshing the page, in order to build the new playlist. Sorry for being dumb!

Comment: OK, thanks I'll have a go at this and will report back

Comment: @Nick there was an error, but it is edited now. To show ' ' in mysql query use \''.$this_path_short.'\'

Comment: I have now got this working using the code you included above.  I added an actual query to playlist.php which is generated from the value in the link, and this correct displays the results from the query on index.php. The issue I am left with is that the original query that builds the playlist (i.e. the query that I need to update) is included in my jPlayer script, i.e. the query dynamically builds the code for the script that generates the playlist.  So I am not sure how to pass the values to the script, as opposed to loading the new content to #content_s, which is what's currently happening.

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use Ajax. The jQuery library is very useful for this.

http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Answer (score 0):

In very big lines:

- Just make an Ajax request with the filters /playList.php?filter=.
- In the repsonse you put only the playlist not the html header and footer.
- Replace the contents of the playlist with the new playlist.

Maybe you can use [jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/)

Answer (score 0):

check this: http://www.datatables.net/ useful plugin

Answer (score -1):

Whenever you want new page content without refreshing a page - solution is AJAX. I cannot explain AJAX in few words but there's an excellent tutorial here:

http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/default.asp

Comment: thanks, I have successfully written some simple AJAX scripts for processing forms, so I have a little knowledge of AJAX.  What I am not sure about is how the AJAX script will interact with the playlist page.  Presumably the best method is to construct the new query from the variables submitted using the form, but I won't be using these variables to construct the query when the page first loads, which is where I am stuck.